# How to retrieving JSON data for android app from WordPress site separately by custom post type, custom meta box, categories, comments, author list

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress

I want to convert `WordPress` site to android app, in my site there have a 4 different types of custom post type, more than 20 custom meta box, also I need to author profile details. The size of `mysql` database more than 500mb.

Please help me how can I retrieving `JSON` for all data separately from `wordpress` database.

Comment: I'm suggesting you the plugin currently I worked with this plugin and I create app for my wordpress site plugins link https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

Comment: Please help me how to restricted JSON page for publicly accessible so that for data secure. You are working currently so I hope you can help me. Thank you :)

Comment: yes we can Also customize for that but I have another plugin for that for disable json https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-json-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has a [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/), there have all defaults objects include and it is possible to [enhance the API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/) for Custom Post type and other data. You should use this default API, there have support, maintenance and will develop with the core.